# Show Weekly VWAP indicator from Tuesday and on

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to show Weekly VWAP that starts on Monday till friday on Indices, but because on Monday the Daily VWAP and the Weekly VWAP has the same value, I would like Weekly VWAP to start showing on charts from Tuesday and on.

PS: I set my indicators to show on chart only on the current week.

I am trying something like this:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Weekly VWAP - Show from Tuesday', shorttitle='VWAP Weekly', overlay=true)

this_week_plot = input.bool(true, "Plot this week only")

vwap_week_plot = input.bool (true,  title='Week VWAP', inline="WEEK VWAP")
vwap_week_color = input.color(color.rgb(102,0,102, 0), title='', inline="WEEK VWAP")
src = input(hlc3, title='', inline="WEEK VWAP")
t = time('W')
start = na(t[1]) or t > t[1]

sumSrc = src * volume
sumVol = volume
sumSrc := start ? sumSrc : sumSrc + sumSrc[1]
sumVol := start ? sumVol : sumVol + sumVol[1]

VWAP_Week = sumSrc / sumVol

var bool novwap_monday = na
if this_week_plot and (dayofweek(time) == dayofweek.monday)
    vwap_week_plot := false
if this_week_plot and (dayofweek(time) == dayofweek.tuesday)
    vwap_week_plot := true
    
if this_week_plot
    novwap_monday := year(timenow) == year(time) and weekofyear(timenow) == weekofyear(time)
if this_week_plot == false
    novwap_monday := year(timenow) == year(time)
    
plot(vwap_week_plot and novwap_monday ? VWAP_Week : na, title='VWAP Week', color=vwap_week_color, linewidth=2)
```

When I use this code the Weekly VWAP does not show on chart on mondays as expected, but from tuesday and on the plot starts from Tuesday, and not from Monday as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build in `ta.vwap` function has an `anchor` parameter which reset of VWAP calculations when true. You can use this parameter to reset the value of VWAP each time the day is Monday :

```
vwap = ta.vwap(source = volume, anchor = dayofweek == dayofweek.monday)
```

Then you can use a ternary operator to show VWAP only on Tuesday onwards:

```
plot(dayofweek == dayofweek.monday ? na : vwap, style = plot.style_linebr)
```

Comment: I didnt know about `ta.vwap` and that has shortened my code alot, Thank you mr_statler. Also I didnt know about using ternary operator with `plot()`. But I just found the solution to the code: `plot(dayofweek(timenow) == dayofweek.monday ? na : vwap, style = plot.style_linebr)`